# Ggplot geom_bar for large dataset in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large scale dataset. I want to plot bar graph for positive and negative value below and above zero in blue and red colors, respectively. It works fine when I have small data, but not for this data (where I have huge range for X-axis). I can see the bars if I add color="black", but not what I wanted. Any suggestions?

```
 tt <- structure(list(values = c(1127879L, 1127880L, 1127881L, 1127882L, 
1127883L, 1127884L, 1127885L, 1127886L, 1127887L, 1127888L, 1127889L, 
1127890L, 1127891L, 1127892L, 1127893L, 1127894L, 1127895L, 1127896L, 
1127897L, 1127898L, 1127899L, 1127900L, 1127901L, 1127902L, 1127903L, 
1127904L, 1127905L, 1127906L, 1635186L, 1635187L, 1635188L, 1635189L, 
1635190L, 1635191L, 1635192L, 1635193L, 1635194L, 1635195L, 1635196L, 
1635197L, 1635198L, 1635199L, 1635200L, 1635201L, 1635202L, 1635203L, 
1635204L, 1635205L, 1635206L, 1635207L, 1635208L, 1635209L, 1635210L, 
1635211L, 1635212L, 1635213L, 1635214L, 1635215L, 1635216L, 1635217L, 
1635218L, 1635219L, 1635220L, 2000104L, 2000105L, 2000106L, 2000107L, 
2000108L, 2000109L, 2000110L, 2000111L, 2000112L, 2000113L, 2000114L, 
2000115L, 2000116L, 2000117L, 2000118L, 2000119L, 2000120L, 2000121L, 
2000122L, 3109790L, 3109791L, 3109792L, 3109793L, 3109794L, 3109795L, 
3109796L, 3109797L, 3109798L, 3109799L, 3109800L, 3109801L, 3109802L, 
3109803L, 3109804L, 3109805L, 3109806L, 3109807L, 3109808L, 3109809L, 
3109810L, 3109811L, 3109812L, 3109813L, 3109814L, 3109815L, 3109816L, 
3109817L, 3109818L, 6123103L, 6123104L, 6123105L, 6123106L, 6123107L, 
6123108L, 6123109L, 6123110L, 6123111L, 6123112L, 6123113L, 6123114L, 
6123115L, 6123116L, 6123117L, 6123118L, 6123119L, 6123120L, 6123121L, 
6123122L, 6123123L, 6123124L, 6123125L, 11932116L, 11932117L, 
11932118L, 11932119L, 11932120L, 11932121L, 11932122L, 11932123L, 
11932124L, 11932125L, 11932126L, 11932127L, 11932128L, 11932129L, 
11932130L, 11932131L, 11932132L, 11932133L, 11932134L, 11932135L, 
11932136L, 11932137L, 11932138L, 11932139L, 11932140L, 11932141L, 
11932142L, 11932143L, 16017144L, 16017145L, 16017146L, 16017147L, 
16017148L, 16017149L, 16017150L, 16017151L, 16017152L, 16017153L, 
16017154L, 16017155L, 16017156L, 16017157L, 16017158L, 16017159L, 
16017160L, 16017161L, 16017162L, 16017163L, 16017164L, 16017165L, 
16017166L, 16017167L, 16017168L, 16017169L, 16017170L, 16017171L, 
20040857L, 20040858L, 20040859L, 20040860L, 20040861L, 20040862L, 
20040863L, 20040864L, 20040865L, 20040866L, 20040867L, 20040868L, 
20040869L, 20040870L, 20040871L, 20040872L, 20040873L, 20040874L, 
20040875L, 20040876L, 20040877L, 20040878L, 20040879L, 20040880L, 
20040881L, 20040882L, 20040883L, 20040884L, 20040885L, 20040886L, 
20040887L, 20040888L, 20040889L, 20040890L, 20040891L, 21558616L, 
21558617L, 21558618L, 21558619L, 21558620L, 21558621L, 21558622L, 
21558623L, 21558624L, 21558625L, 21558626L, 21558627L, 21558628L, 
21558629L, 21558630L, 21558631L, 21558632L, 21558633L, 21558634L, 
21558635L, 21558636L, 21558637L, 21562745L, 21562746L, 21562747L, 
21562748L, 21562749L, 21562750L, 21562751L, 21562752L, 21562753L, 
21562754L, 21562755L, 21562756L, 21569092L, 21569093L, 21569094L, 
21569095L, 21569096L, 21569097L, 21569098L, 21569099L, 21569100L, 
21569101L, 21569102L, 21569103L, 21569104L, 21569105L, 21569106L, 
21569107L, 21569108L, 21569109L, 21569110L, 21569111L, 21569112L, 
21569113L, 21573222L, 21573223L, 21573224L, 21573225L, 21573226L, 
21573227L, 21573228L, 21573229L, 21573230L, 21573231L, 21573232L, 
21573233L, 21579570L, 21579571L, 21579572L, 21579573L, 21579574L, 
21579575L, 21579576L, 21579577L, 21579578L, 21579579L, 21579580L, 
21579581L, 21579582L, 21579583L, 21579584L, 21579585L, 21579586L, 
21579587L, 21579588L, 21579589L, 21579590L, 21579591L, 21583700L, 
21583701L, 21583702L, 21583703L, 21583704L, 21583705L, 21583706L, 
21583707L, 21583708L, 21583709L, 21583710L, 21583711L, 21590024L, 
21590025L, 21590026L, 21590027L, 21590028L, 21590029L, 21590030L, 
21590031L, 21590032L, 21590033L, 21590034L, 21590035L, 21590036L, 
21590037L, 21590038L, 21590039L, 21590040L, 21590041L, 21590042L, 
21590043L, 21590044L, 21594151L, 21594152L, 21594153L, 21594154L, 
21594155L, 21594156L, 21594157L, 21594158L, 21594159L, 21594160L, 
21594161L, 21594162L, 21594163L, 21600508L, 21600509L, 21600510L, 
21600511L, 21600512L, 21600513L, 21600514L, 21600515L, 21600516L, 
21600517L, 21600518L, 21600519L, 21600520L, 21600521L, 21600522L, 
21600523L, 21600524L, 21600525L, 21600526L, 21600527L, 21600528L, 
21600529L, 22716366L, 22716367L, 22716368L, 22716369L, 22716370L, 
22716371L, 22716372L, 22716373L, 22716374L, 22716375L, 22716376L, 
22716377L, 22716378L, 22716379L, 22716380L, 22716381L, 22716382L, 
22716383L, 22716384L, 23278196L, 23278197L, 23278198L, 23278199L, 
23278200L, 23278201L, 23278202L, 23278203L, 23278204L, 23278205L, 
23278206L, 23278207L, 23278208L, 23481761L, 23481762L, 23481763L, 
23481764L, 23481765L, 23481766L, 23481767L, 23481768L, 23481769L, 
23481770L, 23481771L, 23481772L, 23481773L, 23481774L, 23481775L, 
23481776L, 23481777L, 23481778L, 23481779L, 26899510L, 26899511L, 
26899512L, 26899513L, 26899514L, 26899515L, 26899516L, 26899517L, 
26899518L, 26899519L, 26899520L, 26899521L, 26899522L, 26899523L, 
26899524L, 26899525L, 26899526L, 26899527L, 26899528L, 26899529L, 
26899530L, 26899531L, 26899532L, 26899533L, 26899534L, 26899535L, 
26899536L, 26899537L, 34163618L, 34163619L, 34163620L, 34163621L, 
34163622L, 34163623L, 34163624L, 34163625L, 34163626L, 34163627L, 
34163628L, 34163629L, 34163630L, 34163631L, 34163632L, 34163633L, 
34163634L, 34163635L, 34163636L, 34163637L, 34163638L, 34163639L, 
34163640L, 34163641L, 34163642L, 34163643L, 34163644L, 34163645L, 
34163646L, 34163647L, 34163648L, 34163649L, 34163650L, 34163651L, 
34163652L, 36970116L, 36970117L, 36970118L, 36970119L, 36970120L, 
36970121L, 36970122L, 36970123L, 36970124L, 36970125L, 36970126L, 
36970127L, 36970128L, 36970129L, 36970130L, 36970131L, 36970132L, 
36970133L, 26580745L, 26580746L, 26580747L, 26580748L, 26580749L, 
26580750L, 26580751L, 26580752L, 26580753L, 26580754L, 26580755L, 
26580756L, 26580757L, 26580758L, 26580759L, 26580760L, 26580761L, 
26580762L, 26580763L, 26580764L, 26580765L, 26580766L, 26580767L, 
26580768L, 26580769L, 26580770L, 26580771L, 26580772L, 26580773L, 
26580774L, 26580775L, 26580776L, 26580777L), chr = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Ch1", "Ch2", 
"Ch3", "Ch4", "Ch5", "Ch6", "Ch7", "Ch8", "Ch9", "Ch10", "Ch11", 
"Ch12", "Ch13", "Ch14", "Ch15", "Ch16"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("pos_coverage", "neg_coverage"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(28544, 28897, 30108, 31572, 31692, 31830, 31922, 
    32140, 32257, 32520, 32743, 33120, 33271, 33507, 33759, 34191, 
    34213, 34249, 34245, 34242, 34233, 34221, 34102, 34068, 33982, 
    33780, 32515, 21715, 295356, 297538, 301706, 304962, 305965, 
    306218, 306386, 306564, 306576, 306591, 306614, 306626, 306627, 
    306627, 306636, 306648, 306648, 306650, 305173, 305135, 304906, 
    304700, 304419, 302397, 300777, 299865, 299602, 299357, 274455, 
    221100, 209599, 199960, 181882, 103410, 48232, 27967, 28219, 
    28827, 28914, 29008, 29037, 29055, 29133, 29184, 29312, 29333, 
    29707, 29780, 29862, 29979, 30543, 30629, 30663, 30215, 29937, 
    30341, 31001, 31446, 31570, 31604, 31649, 31683, 31685, 31688, 
    31689, 31690, 31690, 31690, 31693, 31697, 31698, 31699, 31384, 
    31366, 31278, 31189, 30863, 29909, 28862, 28449, 28259, 28199, 
    26875, 23675, 23775, 24174, 24175, 24182, 24189, 24196, 24198, 
    24199, 24202, 24224, 24229, 24230, 24232, 24232, 24232, 24232, 
    24230, 22962, 21088, 20986, 20905, 20526, 28367, 28731, 29901, 
    31415, 31557, 31712, 31795, 32003, 32122, 32394, 32608, 33024, 
    33148, 33398, 33658, 34131, 34157, 34190, 34188, 34183, 34172, 
    34152, 34033, 33984, 33906, 33698, 32485, 21492, 28362, 28713, 
    29886, 31378, 31497, 31641, 31725, 31927, 32044, 32275, 32491, 
    32886, 33059, 33287, 33528, 34001, 34015, 34061, 34049, 34045, 
    34038, 34022, 33909, 33853, 33763, 33587, 32339, 21584, 186873, 
    188089, 190977, 191484, 191883, 192552, 193039, 193374, 193518, 
    193601, 193649, 193668, 193679, 193685, 193687, 193689, 193692, 
    193711, 193088, 192908, 192491, 191874, 191156, 185981, 180470, 
    176891, 157803, 157524, 154983, 136508, 60812, 59833, 51027, 
    41116, 34230, 38326, 39084, 39602, 39716, 39811, 39962, 40011, 
    40044, 40085, 40082, 40083, 40085, 40092, 40115, 40120, 40138, 
    40155, 40156, 38936, 35751, 32497, 23747, 20348, 20837, 20974, 
    21155, 21281, 21348, 21368, 21353, 21296, 21208, 20715, 20258, 
    38630, 39411, 39912, 40021, 40102, 40258, 40305, 40347, 40374, 
    40375, 40375, 40379, 40387, 40399, 40407, 40423, 40443, 40443, 
    39101, 35940, 32690, 23741, 20268, 20774, 20935, 21080, 21191, 
    21262, 21266, 21242, 21177, 21073, 20651, 20234, 38455, 39220, 
    39721, 39827, 39894, 40051, 40093, 40132, 40165, 40166, 40169, 
    40171, 40177, 40197, 40199, 40219, 40236, 40233, 38868, 35667, 
    32436, 23500, 20325, 20840, 20994, 21153, 21284, 21347, 21338, 
    21322, 21257, 21166, 20671, 20275, 27026, 27539, 27792, 27835, 
    27859, 27903, 27927, 27946, 27958, 27958, 27958, 27958, 27950, 
    27950, 27942, 27941, 27941, 27930, 26616, 23402, 20062, 20027, 
    20441, 20941, 21097, 21238, 21354, 21413, 21433, 21422, 21342, 
    21236, 20782, 20352, 38667, 39437, 39902, 40004, 40081, 40224, 
    40282, 40313, 40344, 40345, 40349, 40350, 40356, 40364, 40369, 
    40383, 40394, 40396, 39103, 35818, 32476, 23402, 27800, 28025, 
    28663, 28747, 28807, 28836, 28849, 28926, 28981, 29114, 29135, 
    29512, 29578, 29674, 29765, 30338, 30422, 30459, 30021, 21793, 
    21786, 21776, 21447, 22593, 22570, 22592, 22689, 22674, 22128, 
    21831, 21537, 20882, 27666, 27917, 28576, 28660, 28737, 28768, 
    28790, 28879, 28926, 29031, 29053, 29423, 29495, 29579, 29677, 
    30257, 30364, 30401, 29902, 28327, 28684, 29825, 31293, 31415, 
    31533, 31624, 31865, 32006, 32252, 32467, 32852, 32990, 33235, 
    33479, 33935, 33953, 34000, 33993, 33990, 33971, 33958, 33814, 
    33764, 33701, 33511, 32275, 21654, 294463, 296652, 300840, 
    304183, 305104, 305384, 305547, 305720, 305734, 305748, 305773, 
    305778, 305778, 305779, 305784, 305793, 305788, 305786, 304283, 
    304240, 304016, 303794, 303518, 301529, 299873, 299014, 298748, 
    298506, 273729, 219760, 208173, 198820, 180802, 102799, 47734, 
    20297, 20838, 20851, 20857, 20863, 20869, 20869, 20871, 20871, 
    20872, 20872, 20874, 20875, 20876, 20877, 20884, 20889, 20888, 
    -22269, -22279, -23245, -24034, -24002, -24126, -24128, -24091, 
    -24092, -24100, -24161, -24048, -23892, -23857, -23829, -23970, 
    -23852, -23831, -23720, -23666, -23643, -23612, -23598, -23568, 
    -23518, -23466, -23322, -23185, -22899, -22783, -22387, -21818, 
    -20954)), .Names = c("values", "chr", "variable", "value"
), row.names = c(1127879L, 1127880L, 1127881L, 1127882L, 1127883L, 
1127884L, 1127885L, 1127886L, 1127887L, 1127888L, 1127889L, 1127890L, 
1127891L, 1127892L, 1127893L, 1127894L, 1127895L, 1127896L, 1127897L, 
1127898L, 1127899L, 1127900L, 1127901L, 1127902L, 1127903L, 1127904L, 
1127905L, 1127906L, 1635186L, 1635187L, 1635188L, 1635189L, 1635190L, 
1635191L, 1635192L, 1635193L, 1635194L, 1635195L, 1635196L, 1635197L, 
1635198L, 1635199L, 1635200L, 1635201L, 1635202L, 1635203L, 1635204L, 
1635205L, 1635206L, 1635207L, 1635208L, 1635209L, 1635210L, 1635211L, 
1635212L, 1635213L, 1635214L, 1635215L, 1635216L, 1635217L, 1635218L, 
1635219L, 1635220L, 2000105L, 2000106L, 2000107L, 2000108L, 2000109L, 
2000110L, 2000111L, 2000112L, 2000113L, 2000114L, 2000115L, 2000116L, 
2000117L, 2000118L, 2000119L, 2000120L, 2000121L, 2000122L, 2000123L, 
3109791L, 3109792L, 3109793L, 3109794L, 3109795L, 3109796L, 3109797L, 
3109798L, 3109799L, 3109800L, 3109801L, 3109802L, 3109803L, 3109804L, 
3109805L, 3109806L, 3109807L, 3109808L, 3109809L, 3109810L, 3109811L, 
3109812L, 3109813L, 3109814L, 3109815L, 3109816L, 3109817L, 3109818L, 
3109819L, 6123104L, 6123105L, 6123106L, 6123107L, 6123108L, 6123109L, 
6123110L, 6123111L, 6123112L, 6123113L, 6123114L, 6123115L, 6123116L, 
6123117L, 6123118L, 6123119L, 6123120L, 6123121L, 6123122L, 6123123L, 
6123124L, 6123125L, 6123126L, 11932117L, 11932118L, 11932119L, 
11932120L, 11932121L, 11932122L, 11932123L, 11932124L, 11932125L, 
11932126L, 11932127L, 11932128L, 11932129L, 11932130L, 11932131L, 
11932132L, 11932133L, 11932134L, 11932135L, 11932136L, 11932137L, 
11932138L, 11932139L, 11932140L, 11932141L, 11932142L, 11932143L, 
11932144L, 16017145L, 16017146L, 16017147L, 16017148L, 16017149L, 
16017150L, 16017151L, 16017152L, 16017153L, 16017154L, 16017155L, 
16017156L, 16017157L, 16017158L, 16017159L, 16017160L, 16017161L, 
16017162L, 16017163L, 16017164L, 16017165L, 16017166L, 16017167L, 
16017168L, 16017169L, 16017170L, 16017171L, 16017172L, 20040858L, 
20040859L, 20040860L, 20040861L, 20040862L, 20040863L, 20040864L, 
20040865L, 20040866L, 20040867L, 20040868L, 20040869L, 20040870L, 
20040871L, 20040872L, 20040873L, 20040874L, 20040875L, 20040876L, 
20040877L, 20040878L, 20040879L, 20040880L, 20040881L, 20040882L, 
20040883L, 20040884L, 20040885L, 20040886L, 20040887L, 20040888L, 
20040889L, 20040890L, 20040891L, 20040892L, 21558617L, 21558618L, 
21558619L, 21558620L, 21558621L, 21558622L, 21558623L, 21558624L, 
21558625L, 21558626L, 21558627L, 21558628L, 21558629L, 21558630L, 
21558631L, 21558632L, 21558633L, 21558634L, 21558635L, 21558636L, 
21558637L, 21558638L, 21562746L, 21562747L, 21562748L, 21562749L, 
21562750L, 21562751L, 21562752L, 21562753L, 21562754L, 21562755L, 
21562756L, 21562757L, 21569093L, 21569094L, 21569095L, 21569096L, 
21569097L, 21569098L, 21569099L, 21569100L, 21569101L, 21569102L, 
21569103L, 21569104L, 21569105L, 21569106L, 21569107L, 21569108L, 
21569109L, 21569110L, 21569111L, 21569112L, 21569113L, 21569114L, 
21573223L, 21573224L, 21573225L, 21573226L, 21573227L, 21573228L, 
21573229L, 21573230L, 21573231L, 21573232L, 21573233L, 21573234L, 
21579571L, 21579572L, 21579573L, 21579574L, 21579575L, 21579576L, 
21579577L, 21579578L, 21579579L, 21579580L, 21579581L, 21579582L, 
21579583L, 21579584L, 21579585L, 21579586L, 21579587L, 21579588L, 
21579589L, 21579590L, 21579591L, 21579592L, 21583701L, 21583702L, 
21583703L, 21583704L, 21583705L, 21583706L, 21583707L, 21583708L, 
21583709L, 21583710L, 21583711L, 21583712L, 21590025L, 21590026L, 
21590027L, 21590028L, 21590029L, 21590030L, 21590031L, 21590032L, 
21590033L, 21590034L, 21590035L, 21590036L, 21590037L, 21590038L, 
21590039L, 21590040L, 21590041L, 21590042L, 21590043L, 21590044L, 
21590045L, 21594152L, 21594153L, 21594154L, 21594155L, 21594156L, 
21594157L, 21594158L, 21594159L, 21594160L, 21594161L, 21594162L, 
21594163L, 21594164L, 21600509L, 21600510L, 21600511L, 21600512L, 
21600513L, 21600514L, 21600515L, 21600516L, 21600517L, 21600518L, 
21600519L, 21600520L, 21600521L, 21600522L, 21600523L, 21600524L, 
21600525L, 21600526L, 21600527L, 21600528L, 21600529L, 21600530L, 
22716367L, 22716368L, 22716369L, 22716370L, 22716371L, 22716372L, 
22716373L, 22716374L, 22716375L, 22716376L, 22716377L, 22716378L, 
22716379L, 22716380L, 22716381L, 22716382L, 22716383L, 22716384L, 
22716385L, 23278197L, 23278198L, 23278199L, 23278200L, 23278201L, 
23278202L, 23278203L, 23278204L, 23278205L, 23278206L, 23278207L, 
23278208L, 23278209L, 23481762L, 23481763L, 23481764L, 23481765L, 
23481766L, 23481767L, 23481768L, 23481769L, 23481770L, 23481771L, 
23481772L, 23481773L, 23481774L, 23481775L, 23481776L, 23481777L, 
23481778L, 23481779L, 23481780L, 26899511L, 26899512L, 26899513L, 
26899514L, 26899515L, 26899516L, 26899517L, 26899518L, 26899519L, 
26899520L, 26899521L, 26899522L, 26899523L, 26899524L, 26899525L, 
26899526L, 26899527L, 26899528L, 26899529L, 26899530L, 26899531L, 
26899532L, 26899533L, 26899534L, 26899535L, 26899536L, 26899537L, 
26899538L, 34163619L, 34163620L, 34163621L, 34163622L, 34163623L, 
34163624L, 34163625L, 34163626L, 34163627L, 34163628L, 34163629L, 
34163630L, 34163631L, 34163632L, 34163633L, 34163634L, 34163635L, 
34163636L, 34163637L, 34163638L, 34163639L, 34163640L, 34163641L, 
34163642L, 34163643L, 34163644L, 34163645L, 34163646L, 34163647L, 
34163648L, 34163649L, 34163650L, 34163651L, 34163652L, 34163653L, 
36970117L, 36970118L, 36970119L, 36970120L, 36970121L, 36970122L, 
36970123L, 36970124L, 36970125L, 36970126L, 36970127L, 36970128L, 
36970129L, 36970130L, 36970131L, 36970132L, 36970133L, 36970134L, 
65487344L, 65487345L, 65487346L, 65487347L, 65487348L, 65487349L, 
65487350L, 65487351L, 65487352L, 65487353L, 65487354L, 65487355L, 
65487356L, 65487357L, 65487358L, 65487359L, 65487360L, 65487361L, 
65487362L, 65487363L, 65487364L, 65487365L, 65487366L, 65487367L, 
65487368L, 65487369L, 65487370L, 65487371L, 65487372L, 65487373L, 
65487374L, 65487375L, 65487376L), class = "data.frame")
```

Plot

```
ggplot(tt, aes(values, value)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = value < 0)) +
        # geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = value < 0), color="black") +
        scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE, breaks = c(TRUE, FALSE), values=c("blue", "red"))+
        scale_y_continuous("Coverage") +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1419421, 3184713, 5000345, 6846291, 8724752, 10776994, 12882490, 15005355, 17304861, 19739543, 22223374, 25046338, 27919656, 31271109, 34954615, 38906597), labels = c( "Chr1",  "Chr2" , "Chr3",  "Chr4",  "Chr5",  "Chr6",  "Chr7" , "Chr8",  "Chr9",  "Chr10", "Chr11", "Chr12", "Chr13", "Chr14", "Chr15", "Chr16"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So then perhaps blue and red as `color` rather than `fill`?

```
ggplot(tt, aes(values, value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(color = value < 0)) +
  scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, breaks = c(TRUE, FALSE), values = c("red", "blue"))+
  scale_y_continuous("Coverage") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1419421, 3184713, 5000345, 6846291, 8724752, 10776994, 12882490, 15005355, 17304861, 19739543, 22223374, 25046338, 27919656, 31271109, 34954615, 38906597), labels = c( "Chr1",  "Chr2" , "Chr3",  "Chr4",  "Chr5",  "Chr6",  "Chr7" , "Chr8",  "Chr9",  "Chr10", "Chr11", "Chr12", "Chr13", "Chr14", "Chr15", "Chr16"))
```

[image]

Comment: @MAPK, I guess you need to clarify the "but not what I wanted" part. Am I right that there should also be many more bars?

Comment: You are right, but I have subset the data to include values above 1000o coverage.